# how to select margin for a background image in CSS/CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I am not sure why setting width and height to 70% didn't work. Is there anyway, to fix this so we can have margin on all 4 sides of the image? Like I want to have 30% of the page from top, bottom and left and right to be wide and the rest be taken by the background image.

```
<style type="text/css">body {

background-image:url('https://uwmadison.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_00pfOKSXTudGqfb');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 70%;
height: 70%;



}
</style>
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/b3sLz/) the jsfiddle just in case.

Comment: So the `width` and `height` should be `40%` (100% - 30% * 2) not 70%, check this demo for how http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/b3sLz/2/

Comment: what is this for? height:100vh;

Comment: the `background-size` is relative to the body's size, so we have to set its height explicitly to some value, in this case `100vh` means 100% of the viewport height, the width of body is 100% by default, you can try removing that line and see how it looks.

Comment: Is the desired end result something to the effect of this?: http://wistia.com/wistiafest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the flex properie and background-size: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b3sLz/8/)**

```
html {
    height:100%;/* size that body can inherit or use as reference */
    width:100%;/* size that body can inherit or use as reference */
    background:black;/* background needs to set and be different from body, else it is drawn here */
    display:flex;/* the magic that everybody will love */
}
body {
    margin:auto;/* within a flex container it applys on both axis */
    background-image:url('https://uwmadison.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_00pfOKSXTudGqfb');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:70vw 70vh;/* if you use flex, you may use vx units too :) */
}
```

Or display:table/table-cell properties and background-size: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b3sLz/7/)**

```
html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    display:table;
}
body {
    display:table-cell;
    background-image:url('https://uwmadison.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_00pfOKSXTudGqfb');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:70% 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to do it with CSS alone. Here is a fiddle accomplishing what I think you're after. You can use 4 empty divs and style them with CSS fixing their position on the page in the appropriate locations:

http://jsfiddle.net/stacigh/A5J6J/

The HTML:

```
<div class="border-top"></div>
<div class="border-right"></div>
<div class="border-bottom"></div>
<div class="border-left"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/g/1024/768');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.border-top, .border-right, .border-bottom, .border-left {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
   z-index: 3;
}
.border-top, .border-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}
.border-right, .border-left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}
.border-top {
  top: 0;
}
.border-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
.border-right {
  right: 0;
}
.border-left {
  left: 0;
}
```

Of course, if you only want to center the image in the window, you could use this:

```
body {
  background-image: url('path/to/image.png');
  background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-image:url('https://uwmadison.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_00pfOKSXTudGqfb');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 70% 70%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/anMfs/).