# Image doesn't scale according to change in CSS code

Tags: html, css, web

How can I change this code so it will show the image with 70% 70% and like we can have 30% blank margin from all four sides? I don't want to use CSS background properties but want to use the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/LNzwb/4/

html:

```
<div id="bg"><img alt="" src="https://uwmadison.qualtrics.com/CP/Graphic.php?IM=IM_8qcNSb90kC6dqmx" /></div>
```

css:

```
bg{
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 70%; 
  height: 70%;
}
bg.img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 10; 
  left: 10; 
  right: 10; 
  bottom: 10; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: `#bg` to refer element by id in css. Also `10` must has unit, e.g. `10px`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LNzwb/5/ doesn't scale well yet and isn't centered. why?

Comment: Also its "#bg img" not "#bg.img". The selector"#bg.img" would refer to a an element that has id "bg" and class "img".

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to select margin for a background image in CSS/CSS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541713/how-to-select-margin-for-a-background-image-in-css-css3)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check your css selectors. `#something` is for ids, `.something` is for classes, and `something` is pure tags. Also, remember to separate them with a white space.

Second, your math: 70% width leaves 15% on each side, not 30.

Third, just set the image's width and height, and adjust the top and left accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/LNzwb/7/